# Condensed form of Shaiva Purana

Tags: shiva, puranas, shiva-purana, bhakti

Just wondering if there are any works like Narayaneeyam which is a condensed version of Srimad Bhagavatham, similar to Purana of Lord shiva, Shiva Purana, Linga Purana, etc., in Sanskrit language?